# Can I read and post in telegram groups without admin priviledges

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I am new to telegram bots , figured out how to send messages with bot to my group as admin but is it possible to send and read messages to other groups as a member only ?

Answer (score 1):

Bots can read messages in groups only if you set /setprivacy to disabled by @Botfather even bot is admin.
Send messages rights depends of group permissions. By default - any member of Public group can sent messages